# Update new imageTag in values.yaml for ArgoCD Deployment without git push to a protected branch

Tags: github, kubernetes, github-actions, argocd, protected-branches

I have my workflow in Github Actions which builds the Docker Image & Tags it. In the next Job I am updating the image_tag in the values.yaml as below,

```bash
sed -i -e 's/imageTag: .*/'"imageTag: $image_tag/" ./charts/$values.yaml
```

Commit the change & git push using a pat token

```bash
git push https://$Argo@github.com/test/argo-content.git HEAD:test
```

This works fine until we enable Branch Protection Rules, which results in failure with git push.

Have also tried [image: Didn't Work]

Wanted to check if there is any work around updating the image Tag without a git push through scripting.

Need Suggestions.

Comment: What's the exact error message when you do a git push?

Comment: Git push failed and the error says failed to push to protected branch, requires minimum one approver

Comment: Ah I see, so you added the user to allow force-pushing, but that still failed. Same error, I assume.

Comment: Yes the same issue